# The use of 'you'

Tags: grammar

I always find it difficult to use the pronoun 'you' when speaking to my superiors as I am never sure if I show them the respect they deserve. I am Greek and we have two different pronouns for each case.

Comment: English still had distinct familiar/respectful, singular/plural, and subject/object second-person pronouns going into the 16th century, but by about 1750 these had all collapsed into *you*, except in literary and dialect  usage.

Answer (score 2):

English used to have thou (and thee/thy) for singular and casual use, and had you (and ye/your) for plural and polite use. Over time the range of people who were addressed as "you" grew until "thou" completely dropped out of the language (except as used to translate the singular pronoun in the Bible)

So if it makes you feel better, just remember that "you" is already the plural, polite form "*vous* or *εσείς*". You can use "you" in any situation that the polite form would be appropriate.

I mentioned "thou". In Hebrew (apparently in the Greek Bible too?), God is referred to by the singular pronoun "*ἁγιασθήτω τὸ ὄνομά σου". The translators of the Bible translated the singular pronoun with "thou/thee/thy" "Hallowed be thy name". In modern English, this gives "thou" an old-world formal connotation, quite unlike French *tu* or the Greek equivalent.

A comment notes that the thou as an intimate form of you had been lost by 1750, except in dialects. It was retained in some Northern dialects as recently as the 1950s, but is now probably lost by all younger speakers, even in the North of England.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "you" without fear :) I understand where you are coming from as in Russian we have similar "familiar you" vs. "respectful You" way of addressing people, but you will have to live with the fact that in English you show your respect in different manner.
Here is the article on this topic: [Showing your respect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172871/what-is-the-best-way-of-conveying-respect-to-elders-in-english)